# Vim: Insert comment (#) in visual block mode removes leading tabs and only effects first line of block

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to comment many lines in vim in my python script using an Insert in Visual Block mode (Ctrl-V, highlight all the lines, Shift-I, type "# ", Esc twice), but when it does this it will remove all the tabs from the first line in the block and only insert the "# " on the first line. It will not effect any of the other lines highlighted. In short, it only effects the first line and incorrectly deletes the tabs of the one line that is effected. Does anyone know why this is and/or what I am doing wrong?

I am aware I can use this command `:s/^\(\t*\)/\1#` but I would like to do this with Visual Block.

Before:

```
    if(r.is_redirect == False):
        with open(filename,'wb') as output:
            output.write(r.content)
```

Ctrl-V, j, j, Shift-I, "# ", Esc, Esc

After:

```
# if(r.is_redirect == False):
                with open(filename,'wb') as output:
                    output.write(r.content)
```

EDIT: Add proper indentation on Before code

Comment: [It works for me](https://asciinema.org/a/HwW58o14a6zKtiQ6pdqIuOKcI), so I'm inclined to believe it's a configuration issue, not something wrong with your method. Also, why `<Esc>` twice? Once is enough for me.

Comment: Sorry, the Before code didn't have the proper indentation. It works for me as well where the first line is in column one as your demo showed. But when the first line in the block is indented, then it only inserts on the first line. Also, I only indicated <code><Esc></code> twice because that's what a lot of the answers on SO say to do even though I'm pretty sure you only need to do it once.

Comment: try start your vim without any plugins and configs `vim -u NONE` and try again. I am pretty sure it has something todo with a plugin or your `.vimrc`

Comment: Thank you! This ended up working. It turns out `cindent on` is what was causing the problem.